# Windows 8 Tablet App - Webview not supporting HTML 5 and mousover

Tags: c#, windows-8, webview, visual-studio-2013, tablet

In my Windows 8 app using a Webview some websites don't work properly. HTML 5 is not supported well and mouseover effects are buggy as well.

When you hover over a button that has a mouseover-dropdown-menu on windows it just opens, but when you click it in a Webview on a Windows 8 tablet, it does not open the mouseover-dropdown-menu but it performs a  click on that button (leading to a reload of the webpage usally).

Is there a good alternative to Webviews? What is the best way to show Websites on Windows 8 for tablets?

Comment: The problem is not with the web view.Those sites are not optimized for touch.In such a case a web view or any other control cannot do much help

Comment: Well the same websites work perfectly on an iPad in Safari.